# Inserir array dentro de um scopo do angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5

Olá, pessoal, sou iniciante em angular, e gostaria de saber o que eu estou fazendo de errado aqui. Vejam só: Toda vez que eu clico num botão quero ele adicione algumas informações "modificadas" de um objeto chamado partida no objeto apostas. O problema é que na verdade, em vez de adicionar ele ta sobrescrevendo.

Essa é a função:

```
  $scope.fazAposta = function(partida, tipo) {
    var time;
    var partidaA = partida.timeCasa + " x " + partida.timeFora;
    var cotacaoA;
    var idpart = partida.idPartida;
    switch (tipo) {
      case 1:
        cotacaoA = partida.cotTimeC;
        time = partida.timeCasa;
        break;
      case 2:
        cotacaoA = partida.cotTimeF;
        time = partida.timeFora;
        break;
      case 0:
        cotacaoA = partida.cotEmp;
        time = "Empate";
        break;
    }

    $scope.apostas = [
      {timeApostado: time, partidaApostada: partidaA, cotacaoApostada: cotacaoA, idDaPartida: idpart}
    ];

    $scope.apostas.push(angular.copy(apostas));

  }
```

Ah, caso seja necessário de alguma forma, o objeto partida está vindo por ajax feito por um de um script php.

Aqui é onde estou exibindo algumas informações de aposta:

```
  <h3 id="apH3">Apostas Simples</h3>
    <div class='apostado' ng-repeat="aposta in apostas track by $index">
      <h1 name='time'>{{aposta.timeApostado}}</h1>
      <h2 name='partida'>{{aposta.partidaApostada}}</h2>
      <h2 name='cotacaoApostada'>{{aposta.cotacaoApostada}}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha:

```
$scope.apostas = [
  { timeApostado: time, 
    partidaApostada: partidaA, 
    cotacaoApostada: cotacaoA, 
    idDaPartida: idpart }
];
```

Você está setando o valor da propriedade `apostas` do `$scope` atual com um array contendo um membro.

porém na linha seguinte você está executando um push, adicionando mais um objeto.

Seu resultado *sempre* será um array com dois objetos.

Se você quer preservar o array de apostas, mova a inicialização do array para fora do método:

```
.controller('nomeControle', function($scope) {
    $scope.apostas = []; 
    [...]
```

E, no método, realize apenas um `push()`:

```
var aposta = { 
    timeApostado: time, 
    partidaApostada: partidaA, 
    cotacaoApostada: cotacaoA, 
    idDaPartida: idpart };

$scope.apostas.push(aposta);
```

Comment: Obrigado, cara! Ajudou de verdade

Comment: @Krint não por isso, é sempre um prazer. Fico feliz que tenha funcionado!

Answer (score 2):

Olá você está realmente sobre escrevendo o Array. Remove essa parte

```
$scope.apostas = [
      {timeApostado: time, partidaApostada: partidaA, cotacaoApostada: cotacaoA, idDaPartida: idpart}
    ];

    $scope.apostas.push(angular.copy(apostas));
```

E acrescenta o PUSH dessa forma:

```
$scope.apostas.push({
        timeApostado: time, 
        partidaApostada: partidaA,
        cotacaoApostada: cotacaoA, 
        idDaPartida: idpart
    });
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu meio que usei a resposta de vocês dois.

Comment: Muito de nada, estamos aqui para ajudar =)